# how to make my field in many2one?

Tags: drop-down-menu, many-to-one

In openerp i have created many2one field. It has number of customer of my form

xml

```
<field name = "customer_name" on_change="on_change_customer(customer_name)"/>
```

python

```
'customer_name': fields.many2one('res.partner','customer name'),
```

The above code is working fine. It is showing customer name.

but i want to list out the client id. so that i am coding like follow

xml

```
<field name= "client_id" domain="[('client_id','=',True)]" on_change="on_change_customer(client_id)"/>
```

python
    'client_id': fields.many2one('res.partner','Client Id'),

when using this code it is not showing id. it just show only "create and edit"

I want to show client id. what is the problem of my code?

Answer (score 0):

Its usually because when you use many2one method on customer field ,it takes the values of that dropdown list from your 'name' field (this is by default)